# Solving coupled ODEs with unknown parameters

Tags: python, differential-equations, odeint

I am quite new to python, and I am trying to solve a differential equations system with known and unknown parameters. The model has the following equations, where a consumer is maximizing the utility:[image]

I have a starting value D(0) = 0.0274 and the final value is 0.1. k is 0 initially and at the final point. I do not know the parameters A, B, sigma, alpha, beta, and phi. I have tried the below  code but it does not work. How do I optimize this system?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint, solve_ivp

def odes(x,t):
    # known params
    mu = 0.043
    p = 1
    gamma = 0.19
    a = 0.013
    p = 1
    rho = 0.06
    r = 0.06
    q = 1
    w = 1.4
    theta = 0.2
    
    # unknown params
    A = np.zeros(100)
    B = np.zeros(100)
    sigma = np.zeros(100)
    alpha = np.zeros(100)
    beta = np.zeros(100)
    phi = np.zeros(100)
    omega = np.zeros(100)
    c = np.zeros(100)
    
    # assign each ODE to a vector element
    z = x[0]
    D = x[1]
    k = x[2]
    y = x[3]
    h = x[4]
    
    # ODES
    y = (((gamma*A*h**(gamma-1))/(p*omega*B))*(phi+alpha*z-q))**(1/(omega-1))

    dzdt = theta*(y-z)
    dDdt = mu*(D-A*h**gamma+B*y**omega-a)
    dkdt = w+r*k-c-p*h-q*y
    dydt = ((r-rho)/sigma)*y
    dhdt = ((r-mu)/(1-mu))*h
    
    return [dzdt,dDdt,dkdt,dydt,dhdt]

x0 = [0.1,0.0274,0,0.1,0.01]
    

# declare a time vector
t = np.linspace(0,80,160)
x = odeint(odes,x0,t,args=(A,B,sigma,alpha,phi,omega,c))
```

Comment: Could you explain a bit better the problem? Are you optimizing the parameters? finding the trajectory of the system for some initial conditions? do you want the analytical solution of the equation? or what are you doing exactly? It would also be helpful to refactor the code taking unnecessary parameters out of the function etc.

Comment: Yes, of course @PabloRuiz. I am trying to calibrate the model as in [article](https://deliverypdf.ssrn.com/delivery.php?ID=941086029119014013123092103004110030040035068060068038011064123081004086098004002121027055021115000042004088078118086001113123062049001061039125087120103004113069121021022063070006122111003090104112066120002024090122123088112087114006007096069079013117&EXT=pdf&INDEX=TRUE). I need the time trajectories of h, u, z, and D. For D I need it to start at the initial value and end at 0.1 at time T. However, I don't know the parameters A, B, h(t), and u. I hope it makes more sense.

Comment: Do you have calibration data? I would suggest you to put in order the code, taking variables out, and making first successful odeint resolution with some random initial parameters, then we can work in the calibration.